# how to design tab which onselect comes in center of a tabhost

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabhost

I just encountered a problem in layout design with tabhost[image].

[image: i need it like this]

i need exactly the same design so that on selecting a tab it will come in cented of the screen. with design like in these pictures.

Comment: Thanks for your comment . But does this related to my question as you have given me a link how to answer but i asked question here and link to the question is a day older than mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently `ViewPagerIndicator` is the best resource for getting this done without too much code. As for the same design you're going to have to do a little work yourself to get that done. If you look through the samples on the projects github you'll see some examples of how the `ViewPagerIndicator` can be themed.

http://viewpagerindicator.com/